# Select value when no relationship from another table

Tags: sql, left-join

I have 2 tables with 1 column that should have a foreign key but unfortunately no FK constraint was applied and the value inserted became inconsistent

```
table1
--------
id    name    consultant
1    mike         1
2    allan        2
3    jenny        0
4    dan         -1
5    kevin        patrick
6    Sarah        


consultant
----------
id     name
1      steve
2      james
3      craig
```

i have tried

```
SELECT
    table1.id AS id,
    table1.name AS name,
    CASE
        WHEN table1.consultant = '0' OR table1.consultant = '' THEN 'For allocation'
        WHEN table1.consultant = '-1' THEN 'Do not allocate'
        WHEN consultant.id NOT EXISTS THEN CONCAT('Cant find:',table1.consultant)
    END AS consultant_name
FROM
    table1
        LEFT JOIN consultant ON table1.consultant = consultant.id
```

I need to get the result of

```
id    name     consultant_name
1     mike     steve
2     allan    james
3     jenny    'For allocation'
4     dan      'Do not allocate'
5     kevin    'Cant find:patrick'
6     Sarah    'For allocation'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. Add a check against `IS NULL` in first condition of `case`.
2. Use `ISNULL` instead of `NOT EXISTS` in third condition of `case`.
3. Use an `ELSE` part for `case`. Otherwise it will return `NULL` for first 2 records.

**Solution:**

```
SELECT
    table1.id AS id,
    table1.name AS name,
    CASE
        WHEN table1.consultant = '0' OR table1.consultant = '' OR table1.consultant IS NULL THEN 'For allocation'
        WHEN table1.consultant = '-1' THEN 'Do not allocate'
        WHEN consultant.id IS NULL THEN CONCAT('Cant find:',table1.consultant)
        ELSE consultant.name
    END AS consultant_name
FROM
    table1
        LEFT JOIN consultant ON table1.consultant = consultant.id
```

**Result:**

```
id  name    consultant_name
------------------------------
1   mike    steve
2   allan   james
3   jenny   For allocation
4   dan     Do not allocate
5   kevin   Cant find:patrick
6   Sarah   For allocation
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92db0/5)

Comment: @Ponce: No problem, mate. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT
    table1.id AS id,
    table1.name AS name,
    CASE
        WHEN table1.consultant = '0' OR table1.consultant = '' THEN 'For allocation'
        WHEN table1.consultant = '-1' THEN 'Do not allocate'
        WHEN consultant.id is null  THEN CONCAT('Cant find:',table1.consultant)
        ELSE consultant.name
    END AS consultant_name
FROM
    table1
        LEFT JOIN consultant ON table1.consultant = CAST(consultant.id AS varchar(max));
```